# Проблема с синхронизацией времени на сервере Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

Есть 2 сервера находящихся в 1 часовом поясе. Наблюдается проблема с расхождением времени около 70 секунд. В чем может быть проблема, с чего начать, как победить ?

вывод с 1 сервера

```
timedatectl status
  Local time: Ср 2017-11-15 11:48:34 MSK
  Universal time: Ср 2017-11-15 08:48:34 UTC
  RTC time: Ср 2017-11-15 08:48:33
  Time zone: Europe/Moscow (MSK, +0300)
  Network time on: yes
  NTP synchronized: yes
  RTC in local TZ: no


  hwclock 
  Ср 15 ноя 2017 11:53:58 .671399 seconds
```

вывод с 2 сервера

```
timedatectl status
    Local time: Ср 2017-11-15 11:47:18 MSK
    Universal time: Ср 2017-11-15 08:47:18 UTC
    RTC time: Ср 2017-11-15 08:47:18
    Time zone: Europe/Moscow (MSK, +0300)
    Network time on: yes
    NTP synchronized: yes
    RTC in local TZ: no

    hwclock 
    Ср 15 ноя 2017 11:52:51 .452054 seconds
```

Comment: начните с просмотра логов ntpd на том из серверов, который показывает неправильное время.